# Character array initialization and trailing null

Tags: c++

When I declare a char array of size 2 and assign data to it when is there a trailing '\0' (null character)?

I know that:

```
char data[2] = {'a', 'b'}; // array holds 'a', 'b'
```

I also know that

```
char data[] = "ab"; // array holds 'a', 'b', '\0'
```

However, I'm wondering what this does?

```
char data[2] = "ab"; // Is there a trailing '\0'?
```

I always thought that this was an error however looking at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)
it says:

> If the size of the array is known, it **may** be one less than the size of the string literal, in which case the terminating null character is ignored:

```
char str[3] = "abc"; // str has type char[3] and holds 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

So what does "may" mean? Is it implementation dependent?

Comment: The "may" is not about the null character being ignored. You "may" invoke this clause such as you do by writing `char data[2] = "ab"; `.

Comment: The page you are looking at is for C, not C++.  Voting to close as no repro

Comment: @NathanOliver That comment you posted to my (invalid) answer should probably be posted as an answer itself (with a little work).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I voted to close so I'm not going to answer.  If you want to feel free.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You could retract that vote. I think MSVC compiles this sort of thing as if it's C so that's a repro. (I'd need to check though to be sure.) SO works best if there are a selection of answers as we all tend to focus on different things.

Comment: @Bathsheba I can only test 2017 and it fails on that as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver: In which case you have a good point and I'll stop trolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in C++ you must *always* make room for the NUL terminator:

```
char str[3] = "abc";
```

is required to issue a diagnostic.

In C, you can substitute "it is allowed to be" for **may**, and indeed

```
char str[3] = "abc";
```

is permitted, with the NUL terminator not being copied.

This is one of a number of important differences between C and C++.

Answer (score 5):

The declarations that would cause an array overflow don't even compile on MSVC, GCC or Clang:

```
a value of type "const char [3]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char [2]"  

error: initializer-string for char array is too long
```

Etc.